# remove_filter( 'comment_author', 'floated_admin_avatar' ); doesn’t work

Tags: comments, avatar, filters

In a small plugin I’ve written to [add an IP address column to the comments list](https://gist.github.com/1281778) I want to remove the avatars.
In line 156 I tried to use `remove_filter`:

```
remove_filter( 'comment_author', 'floated_admin_avatar', 50 );
```

Well … I know this function [fails sometimes](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/wp-plugins-how-to-remove-a-filter/), but **why does it fail here?**

My workaround is:

```
$_GET['comment_status'] == 'spam' 
    and add_filter( 'pre_option_show_avatars', '__return_zero' );
```

I guess I stared too long at this code to see what went wrong. I need a hint into the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual with hooks this is issue of timing.

- your init function is hooked to admin load process, which works fine for most things;
- however in this specific case function is added to filter in constructor of `WP_Comments_List_Table` class, and object is created in `edit-comments.php` after admin loader had been processed.

In my plugin for similar stuff I am removing it at `manage_edit-comments_columns` hook.

Simplified example from my class:

```
static function on_load() {

    add_action( 'admin_init', array( __CLASS__, 'admin_init' ) );
}

static function admin_init() {

        add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', array( __CLASS__, 'manage_columns' ) );
}

static function manage_columns( $columns ) {

    remove_filter( 'comment_author', 'floated_admin_avatar' );

    // stuff

    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: May just be my coding but when I use the suggested hook I get an awful lot of php foreach errors. @Rarst could you expand your answer with a code example when you get 5? Thanks :)

Comment: @studioromeo added example code

Comment: thanks! I totally forgot about the __CLASS__ magic constant looks better than &$this

Answer (score 0):

May be its the priority 50. Instead let it be default.

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

**$priority**
    (int) (optional) The priority of the function (***as defined when the function was originally hooked***).
    Default: 10

So change

```
remove_filter( 'comment_author', 'floated_admin_avatar', 50 );
```

to

```
remove_filter( 'comment_author', 'floated_admin_avatar');
```

Comment: The priority parameter just says *in which order* to add or remove a filter. I used it without a priority first and this didn't work too.

Comment: When removing an action or filter, you must match the priority exactly, to whatever priority the callback was attached.